# How to combine similar Java functions into one (In C++ I'd use templates)

Tags: java, function, generics

In one of my Java classes I have these 2 very similar functions.  Is there a way in Java to combine them into one function so I don't have to maintain 2 functions?

```
public static boolean areValuesValid( double [] values, int numElements ) {
    if( values == null || values.length != numElements ) {
        return false;
    }
    for( int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i ) {
        if( Double.isNaN( values[i] ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean areValuesValid( float [] values, int numElements ) {
    if( values == null || values.length != numElements ) {
        return false;
    }
    for( int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i ) {
        if( Float.isNaN( values[i] ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Consider using a code-generator, e.g. https://github.com/square/javapoet

Comment: Note that C++ does not combine similar functions into one using templates; templates generate a new function for each different type.

Comment: @Lew Bloch,  yes that is true but I c+h I only need to maintain one template function in my source code rather than two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an ideal scenario, for the reasons @ericbn explained. But here's one way to avoid most of the duplication using a lambda:

```
public static boolean areValuesValid( double [] values, int numElements ) {
    return areValuesValid(values, numElements, i -> !Double.isNaN(values[i]));
}

public static boolean areValuesValid( float[] values, int numElements ) {
    return areValuesValid(values, numElements, i -> !Float.isNaN(values[i]));
}

private static boolean areValuesValid( Object values, int numElements, IntPredicate tester ) {
    if( values == null || Array.getLength(values) != numElements ) {
        return false;
    }
    for( int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i ) {
        if( !tester.test(i) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Looks great thanks!  Only a small logic correction needed inside the for-loop.  The if-statement should not be negated.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is tricky in some ways for Java:

1. `double` and `float` are primitive types, and as such they are not part of a class hierarchy. The wrapper `Double` and `Float` classes extends `Number`, which extends `Object`, but
2. An array of primitive types is not the same as an array of objects, and Java does not autobox a `float[]` to `Float[]`, for example.
3. There is no `isNan(Number n)` or `isNan(Object o)` method in the Java API, but the ones above that you used, that expect a `double` or a `float`. However, you can do `Double.isNan(n.doubleValue())` for any `Number n`.

**TL;DR** In Java the common practice for primitive types is to have separate implementations for each one of them, like you did.

**EDIT:** As @azurefrog suggested:

```
public static boolean areValuesValid(Number[] values, int numElements) {
    if (values == null || values.length != numElements) {
        return false;
    }
    for (Number value : values) {
        if (Double.isNaN(value.doubleValue())) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And then you'd have to use Apache Commons [ArrayUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html):

```
public static boolean areValuesValid(double[] values, int numElements) {
    return areValuesValid(ArrayUtils.toObject(values), numElements);
}

public static boolean areValuesValid(float[] values, int numElements) {
    return areValuesValid(ArrayUtils.toObject(values), numElements);
}
```

**EDIT2:** @shmosel's solution passes the array as an `Object` and from there avoids the conversion of the whole array to a boxed type. A solution worth considering to avoid that overhead.

Comment: Regarding your third point, there is a `Number#doubleValue()` method, so you can just pull the double out of any `Number` and call `Double.isNaN()` on that.

Comment: Regarding your second point, apache [has an ArrayUtils class](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toObject(double[])) that will autobox arrays of primitives for you, if you're willing to pull in third party libraries.

Answer (score -3):

To simplify things, I would use instance of:

```
    public static boolean areValuesValid( Object[] values ) {
    if ( values == null ) {
        return false;
    }
    for( int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i ) {
        //if not Float and not Double return false
        if ( values[i] instanceof Float || values[i] instanceof Double) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am not sure if you really must pass in the numElements.

Comment: `float[]` is not a subclass of `Object[]`.

Comment: You're checking different validation criteria than the OP, who is testing to see if the length of the array is what is expected, and whether it contains any non-number values.